# Python, equating loop and array

Tags: python, arrays, loops, matplotlib, while-loop

i've been trying to figure out how to related numbers obtained from the while loop into an array. can't seem to figure it for some time.

I want to put the obtained Vmax values (between 500 to 600 by 20 increment) using loop into an array, then obtain an another array that relates to the vmax array.

```
import pylab

print "vMax | Time to Land"
print "================================================================================="


sumx = 0
Vmax=500

while Vmax<=600:
if Vmax>=500 and Vmax<=600:
    avesp = pylab.zeros (6,float)
    avesp = ((Vmax + mins)/2.0) #creating formula for average speed
    t = pylab.zeros(6,float)
    t = dT / avesp #formula for time taken
    print Vmax
    sumx = sumx + Vmax
    Vmax = Vmax + 20
    vmax = pylab.array([Vmax],int)
```

Comment: is `vmax = pylab.array([Vmax],int)` a typo or declared elsewhere in unshown code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to build your lists and apply sum function to get the result. 
Something like this:

```
   result = [f2(r) for r in [f1(v) for v in range(500, 600, 20)]]
   sum_r = sum(result)
```